# Errors were encountered while processing: python-minimal

Tags: wireless, system-installation, sudo, system-settings, python-2.7

I am continuously getting this error
 **Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal**
after I try to install anything through *sudo apt-get install ...*.Initially, my enable wifi option disappeared from my ubuntu and now system settings have disappeared.
Please fix this bug.

Comment: The output is
ImportError: No module named _struct
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Download a clean copy of the `python-minimal` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com, and then use dpkg (not apt) to install the package.